# How to redirect the non-hash URL to URL with hash in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

So the user receives an URL, it looks like `http://myapp.com/foo`.

Since my Angular's app routing is working "with hash", the proper component is available under `http://myapp.com/#/foo`.

And because I have a route like:

```
{ path: '',   redirectTo: '/mainpage', pathMatch: 'full' }
```

the `http://myapp.com/foo` is handled by it and gets redirected to `http://myapp.com/#/mainpage`

What I want to achieve is to do a redirect from `http://myapp.com/foo` to `http://myapp.com/#/foo`. And of course I want to keep the redirect to /#/mainpage like it works now.

How do I do that in Angular 7?
If only the `redirectTo` param could take the function as value instead of string, and let me handle the redirect there on my own, that would be something. But I'm afraid it's not possible.

// Update

What I came up with is using a `InitialRedirectGuard` and an empty children array instead of `redirectTo` for `path: ''` object.

```
    path: '',
    children: [],
    canActivate: [InitialRedirectGuard],
    pathMatch: 'full',
```

The logic for redirect lays in InitialRedirectGuard, where I use window.location.pathname to see the URL Im coming from. And then the router.navigate happens. Not cool, I guess, but seems to work.

Comment: Is there any reason you need to use the "with hash" strategy? What's stopping you from declaring a route with path "foo" instead?

Comment: @radzik Do you still need help with this question? I might have a solution, but I realise this question has been inactive for a while.

Comment: @wentjun I have just put it here yesterday, so yes, still looking for solution, I (and for sure some others :)) would be glad to see your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add the `script` below to your `index.html`. What it does is check your URL for /#/ and not found, it redirects to it's equivalent /#/ route.

So visiting `http://myapp.com/foo` would redirect to `http://myapp.com/#/foo`

```
<script>
  // auto redirect to hash# URL
  if (!window.location.href.match(/\/#/)) {
    window.location.href = window.location.origin + '/#' + window.location.pathname + window.location.search;
  }
</script>
```